# Should I separate account from personal info in database?

Tags: database-design

Thinking about the database design for my next web app and considering having separate tables for user account info such as username, password etc and personal info like name, address etc. would that be a good idea or does it really not matter either way?

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be a good idea if you're going to implement database encryption. For example, if you're going to encrypt the password column in your user info table, but your database only supports entire-table encryption, you might split the data to be encrypted into a separate table to minimize overhead. (I'm not advocating database encryption per se, you should also look at application-managed encrpytion depending on your needs.)

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter unless the architecture of the app provokes such requirement. Normally in MVC which is applied to most web app this days, the structure of the table should mirror how the models are set up. That being said, the way your data is organized should reflect the relation between models(objects). If each user shall have only one username, password etc, all information that abstracts a user shall stay together in one table. Unless you run in to a position like the one @pelazem describes, but I am not a big fan of full database encryption either.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep data in a single table.

- You may frequently need to join the two tables having a 1-1 relation, favoring perf problems
- I don't see any security reason why splitting the table would be better than keeping all data in one.

Answer (score 0):

The only good reason I can think of to do so would be if you're going to have multiple users that share the same address.

However, I think the benefits of avoiding the data duplication are outweighed by the performance and simplicity benefits of using a single table.  It's likely to be rare that two users have the same address.

Comment: Hmmm... good point here, what if a user has multiple addresses? Home, work, or maybe vacation home, school, etc.

Comment: Multiple addresses per user is a good reason to *add a table* to store multiple addresses per user. But multiple users sharing one address doesn't require more than one table. Neither does multiple users sharing one last name.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a scenario, within an organization, a person has more than one role or position, this may be temporary or permanent, but every role or position has a different `user` in logic perspective!

Such a situation needs to have different tables for `user` and `person`, so different users point to one person.

In addition to tracking users and history, may I suggest having a [`title`, `role` or `position`] field for `user` table, then every log record must contain both of `user.id` and `person.id`, it will read `person.fullName` did something as `user.title`...